# Add template for taxonomies to Blogdown default theme

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I seek to add tags and categories to the default blogdown theme (hugo-lithium theme).

As a first step, config.toml is configured to include Categories and Tags links in the theme's main menu:

```
[[menu.main]]
    name = "Categories"
    url = "/categories/"
    weight = 2
[[menu.main]]
    name = "Tags"
    url = "/tags/"
    weight = 3
```

Clicking the Categories link displays:

```
Index of ./categories/ 
Name    Size    Date Modified 
./              2017-09-15 09:55:53 
../             2017-09-16 22:03:12 
r/              2017-09-15 09:55:53 
index.xml  695 B    2017-09-17 14:25:01
```

Clicking the Tags links displays:

```
Index of ./tags/
Name    Size    Date Modified
./              2017-09-15 15:31:46
../             2017-09-16 22:03:12
aws/            2017-09-15 15:31:46
openemr/        2017-09-15 15:31:46
plot/           2017-09-15 09:55:53
r-markdown/     2017-09-15 09:55:53
regression/     2017-09-15 09:55:53
index.xml  1,199 B  2017-09-17 14:36:01
```

A better user experience is sought for manipulating the bog via Categories and Tags.  I know it exists as I've seen it in other themes.

I understand the problem to be that the template for taxonomies (terms.html) is not in the theme, so the index pages will not be generated (e.g., tags/index.html).

How would one go about adding the template for taxonomies (terms.html) to the theme for a reasonable user for subsetting blog posts listings by categories and tag?

Comment: Posted related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71133170/add-tags-to-post-summaries-of-lithium-themed-hugo-blogdown-website asking how to get tags to show-up on summaries/previews of posts.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, this question has been cross-posted [on Github](https://github.com/rbind/support/issues/83).

The hugo-lithium-theme does not have the template for taxonomies (`terms.html`), so the index pages will not be generated (e.g., `tags/index.html`). If you want to add it, I recommend you to spend some time on learning more about Hugo themes and templates in the **blogdown** book: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/templates.html, and add the template `terms.html` to the `_default/` folder.