# Add tags to post summaries of lithium themed hugo blogdown website

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

Using the guidance linked to at [Add template for taxonomies to Blogdown default theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46305032/9059865) I was able to add tags to show-up at the top of my posts and create a [/tags](https://www.bryanshalloway.com/tags/) page -- for my lithium themed hugo blogdown website.

How can I have the post tags show-up in the *summaries* of my lithium themed site (i.e. so they show-up on the home page)?

[image]

(https://www.bryanshalloway.com/ ; [source code on github](https://github.com/brshallo/brshallo))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the following HTML to your `layouts/_default/list.html` template, inside the `<article>` tag and after the `<div class="summary">`.

```html
{{ with (.GetTerms "tags") }}
    <div class="tags">
    {{ range . }}
      <div class="tag">
        <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .LinkTitle }}</a>
      </div>
    {{ end }}
    </div>
{{ end }}
```

Then to make it look better, you can add some CSS similar to this:

```css
.tags {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    gap: 8px;
}
.tags .tag {
    /* override the `margin: auto;` rule which applies to all divs and iframes,
     * defined in main.css */
    margin: 0;

    font-size: small;
}
```

Here is how it looks with the code I provided:

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmUSM.png)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! And thanks for such explicit instructions.